# Firebase for chat message alert (push notification)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a chat app using firebase real-time database. I am able to exchange messages but i want to have a message alert notification for new messages. 
Sending notifications using firebase console is working but now i want to automate it without firebase console.

Do i need to create my own app server for push notification between android clients? Or is there another way to achieve this instead of creating a server?

Thank you

Comment: This question is not a duplicate! The question pointed as its duplicate has nothing do to with dispatching notification in real time database chat. That is just for Simple FCM notification scenario not chat. This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase realtime database is very useful precisely for its "realtime" aspect.

You could create a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that listens for changes in the database and create a [Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) whenever the client receives a new message.